# With REST, do you use a body or query params when creating a Resource?

Tags: api, rest

I'm working on a digital media library where users can create entries for a Media resource.

The media resource is made up of tons of properties, eg:

```
Media:{
  id, 
  name,
  type,
  private,
}
```

the url users use to create a resource is

```
POST api/media
```

On the backend, we are creating the resource with a UID generated for them while defaulting name, type and private values. However, users can pass in name, type, private if they choose to.

RFC 4.3.3 doesn't seem to have an opinion on whether or not to use params or post body for these data.

So is it better to do this

```
api/media?type="audio"&name="Hopkins County Collective"&private=false
```

or with a body instead?

```
api/media

body{
   name:
   type:
   private:
}
```

Althought after reading section 4.3.3 for POST here https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3 and I see this piece

```
Providing a block of data, such as the fields entered into an HTML
      form, to a data-handling process;
```

I'm leaning toward the post fields in the body but I'm still unsure.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> do you use a body or query params when creating a Resource?

The Body.  But it can be more complicated than that.

HTTP gives us standardized message semantics - we all agree, by adopting the common standard, what a given message means.  That doesn't necessarily constraint what we *do* with the message when we get it.

For example.

```
PUT /id=1 HTTP/?.?
Content-Type: text/plain

id=2
```

That message *means* that we want the resource identified by `/id=1` to have the representation `id=2`.  In other words, this is the future behavior intended by the client

```
GET /id=1 HTTP/?.?
```

```
200 OK
Content-Location: /id=1
Content-Type: text/plain

id=2
```

So the body describes what we want the representation to be, and the effective-uri identifies which document we are talking about.

The same basic pattern holds for POST and PATCH - the effective-uri tells us which resource we want to change, the body describes that change.

BUT...

You the server aren't actually required to do what the request asks you to do.  You can reject the request (4xx), or you can do something similar to the request, and tell the client about that.

So you might, as part of the implementation hidden behind your REST facade, copy information from the effective-uri in addition to, or instead of, exactly applying the instructions provided by the client in the body of the request.  (You have to be a little bit careful with the response metadata to ensure there's no ambiguity about what you did do).

Answer (score 1):

Anecdotally, "just about everyone" seems to be using the body to represent what they want the created resource to look like, be, or contain.

Parameters are often not likely to be used at all, and if they are, only for, perhaps, controlling aspects of how that resource is to be created, not anything having to do with what the resource is to look like, be, or contain.

I say anecdotal, because I'm sure there are exceptions to this --  you're even contemplating it. That said, REST does not specifically say anything about parameters vs. body.

For the sake of conformity, and for the sake of "doing it like everyone else", go with body.

There are other considerations pointing away from parameters: 1) they are part of the URI, and URIs are used for identification purposes, 2) the query string length is highly constrained, so would prevent creating large objects, and 3) it would be a diagnostics/debugging nightmare parsing the query string in your head trying to make sense of it.